# How do i check what time request is fulfilled in unix time python

Tags: python, unix, time, python-requests, epoch

```
import requests
import time

def get_response_time():
    r = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
    print(time.time())

while True:
    if time.time() > 1649870850:
        get_response_time()
```

it prints the time as 1649870850.1155915 so 100ms off i know there is delay but i still have a feeling the time it prints isnt the actual time the request was accepted.Is this code actually printing the time that the request has been accepted?

Comment: The response headers include a `"Date"` field - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: The date object does not return the millisecond the request was sent